# R make print use row major order

Tags: r

Is it possible to tell R to use row major order instead of column major order when printing arrays, so that **array(1:9,c(3,3))** prints out

```
     [1,] [2,] [3,]
[,1]    1    2    3
[,2]    4    5    6
[,3]    7    8    9
```

instead of

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

?

Comment: You could use `matrix` to create.  `m1 <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)` and `t(m1)` or `byrow=TRUE`

Comment: Or with `matrix` function: `matrix(1:9, 3, 3, byrow = TRUE)`.

Comment: I think just `matrix(1:9, 3, byrow = TRUE)` should be enough. But this is basically what akrun already suggested.

Comment: nope, there's a subtle but important difference between transposing the data and transposing the print (which also transposes the column/row descriptors but t(...) does not)

Comment: If you are using `array`, then `aperm(array(1:9, c(3,3)),c(2,1))`